# How to Pass data to phone app dialer from recyclerview holder data is parse from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I get data from firebase database to manipulate.

`viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener` to open phone app and show phone number from model.getPhone();
and show it in phone dialer to give preference user wather to call or not.
app crash when I click imageButton and i'm not able to get crash log in android studio.

```
 @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, final Movie model, final int position) {
                if (tvNoMovies.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    tvNoMovies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                viewHolder.tvMovieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
                viewHolder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
                viewHolder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                viewHolder.lit.setText(model.getLit());
                viewHolder.lon.setText(model.getLon());
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
                viewHolder.ivMoviePoster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("latitude", model.getLit());
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", model.getLon());
                        intent.putExtra("name", model.getMovieName());


                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                viewHolder.tvMovieName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("latitude", model.getLit());
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", model.getLon());
                        intent.putExtra("name", model.getMovieName());


                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    String mobileNo = model.getPhone();
                    String uri = "tel:" + mobileNo.trim();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });



// all your stuff

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have permission to make calls?

You need the CALL_PHONE permission. Make sure you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

My other guess is `mobileNo` is null when you are trying to call `mobileNo.trim()`.

The only way to know for sure is to see the log. You may need to change the logcat view setting on Android Studio to 'Verbose.'

Alternatively you can use `adb logcat` to view the log in a terminal. Watch the log while you replicate the force close and you should be able to find the exception causing it.

Comment: yes I have the call phone  permission 
and I tried  String number = ""+model.getPhone();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
                        startActivity(intent);
it worked for me thank you for your answer